# Is possible to know the design or color of a DualShock 4 (PS4 Controller) with just the sticker?

Tags: ps4, controllers

Let's say that I have only the backplate of a DualShock 4 with the sticker intact. Is possible to know the design or color with just that sticker?

[image]

Comment: What sticker do you mean? Would help to include a picture. Also what do you mean with design?

Comment: I added a picture showing the sticker on the back. With the design I mean literally the design or color of the controller (Days of Play, Metallic Copper, Blue Camo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the infos I found on the posted sticker I couldn't find any info regarding the design of the controller. Following info refer to the controller itself, but not to the design:

1. MODEL CUH-ZCT2E
2. Barcode: 251425A0218666
3. Series Number(?) 4-472-348-13 F1

Yet none of these refer to the design. The only info that also refers to the design seems to be the ASIN, but this one is not included on the sticker.

Because of all this, I say that it's not possible to know the design just from the sticker.